# Cannot use properly (@Inject)

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, cdi

When i try to use @Inject to inject my DAO class, in a manager to make it able to give a gson file to a current address i get this exception when i go to the specific web address.Can someone explain me what is the problem. I thought that the problem come maybe from the @Inject and it does not work correctly, but i am not sure.

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: org.apache.cxf.interceptor.Fault: Cannot obtain a free instance.; nested exception is: 
javax.enterprise.inject.UnsatisfiedResolutionException: Api type [cinema.dao.ProjectionDAO] is not found with the qualifiers 
Qualifiers: [@javax.enterprise.inject.Default()]
for injection into Field Injection Point, field name :  projectionDAO, Bean Owner : [ProjectionManager, Name:null, WebBeans Type:DEPENDENT, API Types:[cinema.services.ProjectionManager,java.lang.Object], Qualifiers:[javax.enterprise.inject.Any,javax.enterprise.inject.Default]] while invoking public java.util.Collection cinema.services.ProjectionManager.getAllProjections() with params [].
org.apache.cxf.interceptor.AbstractFaultChainInitiatorObserver.onMessage(AbstractFaultChainInitiatorObserver.java:116)
org.apache.cxf.phase.PhaseInterceptorChain.doIntercept(PhaseInterceptorChain.java:324)
org.apache.cxf.transport.ChainInitiationObserver.onMessage(ChainInitiationObserver.java:121)
org.apache.cxf.transport.http.AbstractHTTPDestination.invoke(AbstractHTTPDestination.java:240)
org.apache.openejb.server.cxf.rs.CxfRsHttpListener.onMessage(CxfRsHttpListener.java:187)
org.apache.openejb.server.rest.RsServlet.service(RsServlet.java:53)
javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:727)
org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
```

Code for the manager:

```
package cinema.services;

import java.util.Collection;

import javax.ejb.Stateless;
import javax.inject.Inject;
import javax.ws.rs.GET;
import javax.ws.rs.Path;
import javax.ws.rs.Produces;

import cinema.dao.ProjectionDAO;
import cinema.model.Projection;

@Stateless
@Path("projection")
public class ProjectionManager {

    @Inject
    private ProjectionDAO projectionDAO;

    @GET
    @Produces("application/json")
    public Collection<Projection> getAllProjections(){
        return projectionDAO.getAllProjections();
    }

}
```

Here is the ProjectionDAO:

```
package cinema.dao;

import java.util.Collection;

import javax.inject.Singleton;
import javax.persistence.EntityManager;
import javax.persistence.NoResultException;
import javax.persistence.PersistenceContext;

import cinema.model.Projection;
import cinema.model.User;

@Singleton
public class ProjectionDAO {

    @PersistenceContext
    private EntityManager em;


    public Collection<Projection> getAllProjections(){
        return em.createNamedQuery("getAllProjections",     Projection.class).getResultList();
    }

    public void addProjection(Projection projection){

            em.persist(projection);

    }

    public Projection findProjectionByMovieTitle(String movieTitle){
        try {
            return em.createNamedQuery("getProjectionByMovieTitle", Projection.class)
                .setParameter("movieTitle", movieTitle).getSingleResult();
        } catch (NoResultException e){
            return null;
        }
    }

    public void buyTicket(Projection projection, User user){
        Projection foundProjection =     findProjectionByMovieTitle(projection.getMovieTitle());
        if(foundProjection != null){
            user.getCurrentProjections().add(projection);
            int newFreeSpaces = foundProjection.getFreeSpaces() - 1;
            foundProjection.setFreeSpaces(newFreeSpaces);
        }
    }

}
```

Projection is a simple model which give the movieTitle and start time of different projections in a cinema.

Comment: If this is in the same war. Annotate the projection with both applicationscoped and singleton or use '@ejb' instead of '@inject' at the injection point

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your question doesn't state important information such as versions in use or how you're deploying, so I'm going to take a wild stab.

1. You're not including a `beans.xml` file in your deployment.  I'm not sure though if you're deploying a WAR or a JAR file.
2. Assuming you have a properly placed `beans.xml` file, try swapping the `@Singleton` with an `@ApplicationScope`.  This should more correctly discover your class.